# In cytoscape.js, how to create "repeating-linear-gradient"-like style on node?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using JSON to specify the "style" of my graph. I need to make a node to have a background like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEqSt.png). In CSS, it would be:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  white,
  white 10px,
  red 10px,
  red 20px
)
```

How can I do it in the JSON format "style" for cytoscape.js? I tried something like the following:

```
{
    selector: '.someClass',
    style: {
      'background-image': 'repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white, white 10px, red 10px, red 20px)',
    },
}
```

But that doesn't work. Any suggestions how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `repeating-linear-gradient` anywhere in the docs.  Did you carefully read the docs?

Try using a data uri for `background-image` if you want to programmatically create an image.

http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image

Comment: Thanks for answering! I read the docs and know it's not there, I guess I should have phrased my question better. I wanted to ask if there's a way to achieve similar effect, or if there's a generic way to port CSS function in.